# CNAME forwarding in Bigrock isn't working

Tags: subdomain, cname, forwarding

I have a domain in [bigrock](http://www.bigrock.in/) and my app is in [scalingo](https://scalingo.com/). I intend to mask scalingo app with my domain.
I have deleted all previous A records of my [bigrock](http://www.bigrock.in/) domain and updated my CNAME records in bigrock. Its working for naked domain, but isn't working for www subdomain. Previously only www subdomain was in A records.

`host ingion.in` has the following output:

```
ingion.in has address 173.193.105.245
ingion.in is an alias for ingion.scalingo.io.
ingion.scalingo.io is an alias for scalingo.io.
ingion.in is an alias for ingion.scalingo.io.
ingion.scalingo.io is an alias for scalingo.io.
scalingo.io mail is handled by 10 spool.mail.gandi.net.
scalingo.io mail is handled by 50 fb.mail.gandi.net.
```

`host www.ingion.in` has the following output:

```
www.ingion.in has address 180.149.246.140
www.ingion.in is an alias for ingion.scalingo.io.
ingion.scalingo.io is an alias for scalingo.io.
www.ingion.in is an alias for ingion.scalingo.io.
ingion.scalingo.io is an alias for scalingo.io.
scalingo.io mail is handled by 50 fb.mail.gandi.net.
scalingo.io mail is handled by 10 spool.mail.gandi.net.
```

Link to my scalingo app is: [ingion.scalingo.io](http://ingion.scalingo.io/)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was simple. In scalingo dashboard, I am not supposed to add only the naked domain, but also the subdomains I want my app to give access e.g. if you want `yourapp.scalingo.io` be masked by both `yourdomain.com` and `www.yourdomain.com`, you will have to add both `yourdomain.com` and `www.yourdomain.com` in the Domains of the scalingo app dashboard.